# How can I detect when a user returns to a Lightning Component tab from another tab?

Tags: lightning-web-components

Suppose I have surfaced an LWC as a custom tab in a Lightning application by using the `<target>lightning__Tab</target>` in the metadata file. The LWC has some state. If I navigate away to another tab (for instance, a custom object tab) and return to the LWC tab, the state is still there. However, neither renderedCallback() nor connectedCallback() fires on the LWC when returning to the tab. Is there a good way to detect that the user came back?

One use case is wanting to reset some state.

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do this in a console app? I am looking to detect when user activates different tabs within Service Console. I am happy to create an LWC for this but not sure how to detect the different tab clicks. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Answering myself after some help from others!

Applying `NavigationMixin`, importing `CurrentPageReference`, and doing the following allows me to detect it.

```
@wire(CurrentPageReference)
setCurrentPageReference(currentPageReference) {
    console.log('Welcome to the tab ' + (new Date().getTime()) );
}
```

Comment: did you have to implement a LWC to navigate to your LWC tab to achieve this?

Comment: @KrisGoncalves when I was testing this, I tested by 
1. Click LWC tab.
2. Click custom object tab.
3. Click LWC tab again.

Never did anything meaningful with this - it was simply for a proof of concept based on a student question.

Comment: So I now see this does work in standard apps, but it doesn't seem to work in console apps (which is what I was using). Might create my own question. Thanks!